# what is the advantage of using viewmodel commands as compared to the view's click events in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, design-patterns, xamarin

I would like know the advantage of using commands in viewmodel in xamarin as compared to the click event handlers in the view class. Click events seems simpler to use. Please point out the pros and cons of both approches.

Thanks

Comment: That's essentially an architecture decision. When using ViewModels your code is more decoupled from the view, which makes it more flexible regarding of changing the logic in the future. There's a LOT of information about that. Google for advantages of MVVM or ViewModels. Doesn't matter if is xamarin or not, that's a concept

Comment: Another advantage is testability.  I think it's easier to construct unit tests on the ViewModel since it's just a regular class than it is the View.  There is a [video by Jason Dolinger on MVVM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRxnZahCPFQ) that talks a little about this near the end.

Comment: Thanks, 'Your comments were helpful. Please add them as an answer so that I mark them.

Comment: This youtube video really helped clearing thing up
https://youtu.be/sbZRtrKj3Ds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click events are tightly bound to your view and cannot be unit test. Using commands in view model makes the testing process very easy. This is a great view which will help clear thing up in detail. [view models and unit testing](http://youtu.be/sbZRtrKj3Ds)